# Touchscreen troubles

Tags: iphone, repair

I recently had my screen replaced on my I phone 5c from a vender in our local mall. The screen had been previously cracked for about 6 mnths and functioned fine until I dropped the phone after being outside in freezing weather for a few hours. At any rate now it is acting all hay wire like my touch screen doesn't always work properly... I press one thing I get another... Especially if the phone is cold or my hands are hot then the touch screen doesn't work at all... My question is should I be heading back to the mall and asking some questions about my repair? I was reading previous post on calibrating touch screen and I tried a couple ideas... It mentioned something about it being in the front panel which I just had replaced so I'm wondering if I got a faulty repair or if it's something else entirely?

Answer (score 1):

yes - you should head back to the vendor that performed the repair as soon as practical and ask them to have a look at the device - assist with calibration and or perform the repair again if it's not working.

Most locales have a short period where any work is warranted, so be sure to get something in writing from the vendor if they tell you they can't support their work.

Hopefully it will be something they have seen before and know how to remedy and/or reach an agreement that is satisfactory to you both.